# How can I change where the Data Loader success or error files are stored?

Tags: data-loader

When I first ran the Salesforce Data Loader it asked me where it should store the success and error files. I'd like to change that location now. How can I do that? It's not under settings. I've tried searching the registry and looking where the application is stored.

Comment: Data loader asks for the success/error files location every time you run the tasks. By default Dataloader will pick the last success/error files location of last run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time when you insert or update the record using data loader, it always ask where to store the success or errors file.

[image: Data Loader Success/Error File Selection]

Comment: Yes! I use Data Loader so often I just click through that every time, without noticing what is says any more. Thanks.